# After upgrading to flutter 2.10: appears widget's ancestor is unsafe

Tags: flutter, upgrade, unsafe, ancestor

After upgrading to flutter 2.10, the project I'm currently working on has randomly started showing me this message.
Does anyone know what has changed to make this happen? I haven't seen anything relevant in the official documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Just perform flutter clean and flutter run this work for me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).